# Problem with playlist_add_items in spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

Im having trouble with playlist_add_items on spotipy, im trying to add episodes to a new playlist

```
tt = ['https://open.spotify.com/episode/3nwfTNjbhDu8Cnp81TdmGO',
  'https://open.spotify.com/episode/3jZ5bleO9SCYZ0akgXhmpX']
sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=new_playlist_id_, items=tt)
```

I tryed with episode URLs, IDs and URIs and allways get this error:

```
Expected id of type track but found type episode https://open.spotify.com/episode/3nwfTNjbhDu8Cnp81TdmGO
Expected id of type track but found type episode https://open.spotify.com/episode/3jZ5bleO9SCYZ0akgXhmpX
```

And this is what the documentation say:

```
playlist_add_items(playlist_id, items, position=None)
Adds tracks/episodes to a playlist

Parameters:
playlist_id - the id of the playlist
items - a list of track/episode URIs, URLs or IDs
position - the position to add the tracks
```

I tryed with songs URLs and it works...

Answer (score 1):

It worked with this code...

```
sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=playlist_id_new, items=['spotify:episode:3nwfTNjbhDu8Cnp81TdmGO'], position=None)
```

Comment: Yes, this works very well indeed. Been having troubles while thinking what should I pass to this method. Thanks for posting the solution!